# Как получить доступ к сообщениям через python vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Использую python-модуль vk_api (https://github.com/python273/vk_api). Не могу получить доступ к сообщениям аккаунта. Выдает ошибку:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method
```

```py
import vk_api

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('+7964#####','aWeSoMeP@s$w0rD')
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()
messages = vk.messages.get()
```

Есть ли способ получить доступ к сообщениям с помощью vk_api?

Пробовал следующее:

```py
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('+7964#####', 'aWeSoMeP@s$w0rD')
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('+7964#####', 'aWeSoMeP@s$w0rD', 'messages')
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('+7964#####', 'aWeSoMeP@s$w0rD', scope='messages')
```

На выходе та же ошибка

Comment: Вам необходимо получить доступ с правами к скопу https://vk.com/dev/permissions. В Вашем случае messages

Comment: Передача в качестве третьего параметра 'messages' и scope='messages' выдает ту же ошибку((

Comment: Vk изменил формат запросов. Теперь используется метод - messages.getConversations    пример    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": 'all'})

    print(messages)

Comment: При изменении формата запроса на указанный вами всплывает:
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась, когда я подключился используя app_id верифицированного приложения(KAteMobile)

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('+7964#####', 'aWeSoMeP@s$w0rD', app_id=2685278)
vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Например чтобы отправить сообщение просто сформируйте словарь:

```
def write_aud_msg_chat(chat_id, attachment):
    return vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})
```

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
group = '123456789'
wait = 25
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, group, wait)
for event in longpoll.listen():
```

Если же вы хотите авторизоваться с помощью пользователя просто укажите его токен (чтобы его получить перейдите по ссылке и скопируйте из адресной строки то что после acces_token= и до &: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2685278&scope=1073737727&redirect_uri=https://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token&revoke=1 ):

```
vk1 = vk_api.VkApi(token=token1)
```

```
    peer_id = event.object.peer_id
    chat_id = peer_id - 2000000000
    user = event.object.from_id
    mess = event.object.text.lower()
```

Сам код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
def write_msg_chat(chat_id, message):
    return vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
group = '123456789'
wait = 25
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, group, wait)
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        peer_id = event.object.peer_id
        chat_id = peer_id - 2000000000
        user = event.object.from_id
        mess = event.object.text.lower()
        #тут реакция на различные команды
```

Не забудте добавить НУЖНЫЕ импорты:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
```